# Archive Mail send through sendmail service from outlook

Tags: sendmail, archive, solaris-11

I have sendmail running on linux host with email alias group, from outlook I am sending mail through this sendmail server.
Am looking for an option to archive all outgoing mails using this sendmail service running server ?

May I know how to achieve it, I would require some mail ID to kept in Bcc while sending mail from outlook which should archive all messages broadcasted ?

Well I have gone through mailer/copymail.m4 mentioned in https://itecnotes.com/server/linux-configuring-sendmail-to-archive-a-copy-of-any-outgoing-message/ but not sure how that could help my need

Comment: AFAIR modern recommendations suggest using some archiving milter (sendmail helper app).

Answer (score 0):

You can use milter (sendmail/postfix plugin/add-on) for archiving

There are custom milters for the task or you can use multipurpose milter like [MIMEDefang](https://mimedefang.org) (available at very license strict Debian).

MIMEDefang uses perl script to configure filtering so its very configurable,  It can be also used to integrate anti-spam and anti-virus filtering.